# Symfony 3.x multiple kernel configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking for some examples on how to set up a Symfony app with multiple kernels. I only found one example, but it's for Symfony 2.2 and not working for Symfony 3.x.

Does anyone have an example or some GitHub code to share on how to get that working with best practice approach?

Comment: sorry forgot the example I found ```https://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2```

Comment: If you worry about best practice I don't see why you would want to split the kernel. I didn't find any documentation anyway, good luck

Comment: I would agree with you goto but then I find this symfony document [http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/front_controllers_and_kernel.html] in it search for "app/admin/AdminKernel.php". You think they put that there by mistake?

Comment: Hum I've never seen this documentation. Sorry I can't help you :/ Good luck!